# PHP where is this data coming from?

Tags: php

I am trying to implement a drop down for a form of a open source project.
I am looking at line below and wondering where is $organizations coming from?
There is no such indications in the file.

```
{!! Form::select('suggest_organization',$organizations,null,['class'=> 'form-control selectpicker','id' => 'suggest_organization','data-live-search' => 'true','data-size' => '5']) !!}
```

Link to the complete source code: https://github.com/sarapis/orservices/blob/master/resources/views/frontEnd/suggest/create.blade.php

Thank you for your time to help!

Comment: have you tried out laravel before?, usually it's set via your controller that loaded the view. data is injected through there https://github.com/sarapis/orservices/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/frontEnd/SuggestController.php#L36. if it's residing in the `create` view, it's most likely set inside the `create` method from controller

Comment: @Kevin No..I know some of PHP and new to laravel. What is the difference between create and store? I am trying to implement a new function similar to the one above under  service/show.blade.php but I cannot get the list of organization names from db.

Comment: create and store? the create screen shows you the actual page for you to interact with. store does what it does, it stores everything what you provided in create page. you already have the convention to follow, the idea should be the same

Comment: @Kevin I will look in both sections! Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The declaration of the variable is declared in the `app/Http/Controllers/frontEnd/SuggestController.php` file.
You can see it on [this](https://github.com/sarapis/orservices/blob/master/app/Http/Controllers/frontEnd/SuggestController.php#L36) line.

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! It absolutely led me out from the wrong path. If I would like to use the suggest controller in file resources/views/frontEnd/services/show.blade.php, should I copy the functions from the suggestController to serviceController and set the route to be 'route' => 'service.store' or can I directly set the route to be 'route' => 'suggest.store'

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by directly importing the designated table and select wanted columns using pluck in the current php file since I cannot connect the controller.